# ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': No module named urls

Tags: python, django

```
[INFO] oauth2client.client: Refreshing access_token
[ERROR] django.request: Internal Server Error: /
get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': No module named urls
```

This is a python 2.7 project. Django version 1.9

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django Rest Framework 3.7](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/#370) dropped support for Django 1.9.

Django 1.9 is end of life and does not get security fixes. You should really update to the current release 2.0 (requires Python 3) or the 1.11 LTS (supports Python 3 and Python 2).

If you must use Django 1.9, then you'll need to use an earlier version of rest framework.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: But the same project is running on Ubuntu Linux without any problem. And when i am trying to run the project on mac the problem occurs.

Comment: If it's working on one machine and not another, then you have different versions of rest framework installed on the two machines.